# Passing an array of multiple strings with mpi in C

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

im trying to pass 2 array from my master process to the slaves. The problem is when i pass the array i get garbage inside. There is something that i didn't understand?

Declaration outside of the master:

```
int how_much_word[2];
char file_name_and_number_words[2][50];
```

In master the array file_name_and_number_words is filled by "mytext2.txt" and "mytext.txt".
So the master send these 2 array at slave with rank 1 in this way:

```
    for (int tmp = 1; tmp<world_size;tmp++){
        MPI_Send(file_name_and_number_words,2,MPI_CHAR,tmp,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(how_much_word,2,MPI_INT,tmp,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
```

The slave recive in this way:

```
MPI_Recv(file_name_and_number_words,2,MPI_CHAR,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
MPI_Recv(how_much_word,2,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
```

If I try to print: file_name_and_number_words[0] the output is: "my", if I print file_name_and_number_words the output is: "�����b��>�6�9`", I think it's a garbage memory zone. But where is the error?

Comment: Can you confirm prior to `MPI_Send` that the contents of `file_name_and_number_words` and `how_much_word` are actually set correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument to MPI_Send be `sizeof(file_name_and_number_words)/sizeof(file_name_and_number_words[0][0])` for the first call and `sizeof(how_much_word)/sizeof(how_much_word[0])` for the second call? Same kind of fix at the slave.

Comment: yep, in the master section I have a for that loop through the array file_name_and_number_words, and the output is correct. "The file mytxt2.txt has got 6 words" -> parameters are file_name_and_number_words[0] and how_much_words[0]

Comment: @fpiette Yeah, it's correct... but why if i set static size of the array don't work?

Comment: You didn't *set static size of the array*, I did.